# how to add start and stop capability to easySlider jquery plugin on mouseover

Tags: jquery

I am using [easySlider 1.7](http://cssglobe.com/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider/) jQuery plugin for add a SlideShow to [my Designed Website](http://panjohaft.com/).
this plugin has a **auto** option that we can start slides on page load by setting it to **true** value. but when we click on a relative navigation button for go to a slide, slideShow do'n move slides automatically no longer.
i want to add a capability So that when user enter to slideShow section all Slides stop and then start on mouse out event

it is a piece of My Slideshow Code:

```
    <section id="slideShow">
      <div id="slider">
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><img src="timthumb.php?src=uploads/4406f06c590a7a7bb6ab60f36653c7419b8bbfbd.jpg&w=730&h=410"></a></li> 
           <li><a href="#"><img src="timthumb.php?src=uploads/6a56ff2601034e783c4f7cab9a5f0fed6896dcbd.jpg&w=730&h=410"></a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
        </section>
```

And this is my jQuery Code to initialize the plugin

```
$("#slider").easySlider({
                auto: true,
                continuous: true,
                numeric: true,
                speed: 600,
                prevId:         "prevBtn",
                nextId:         "nextBtn"
        });
```

What do I need. is there any solution?

Comment: this is so annoying. talking about User Experience you should really add a `hover intent` to that unusual gallery.

Comment: yes roXon. but it is my customer order and i force to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that this plugin doesn't support that, as far as I understood.
You can modify the code of the plugin to achieve what you want. Here are the modifications (worked for me, i'm using the version 1.7 of the easySlider: easySlider1.7.js):

line 161:
replace 
`t = dir;`
by
`t = parseInt(dir);`

line 198
replace
`if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){;`
by
`if(options.auto)`

that's all